# h2o decision tree leaf value interpretation

Tags: probability, decision-tree, h2o

I want to convert the leaf value into the probability. According to my current understanding, these predicted leaf values are not logodds, but are corrections. I want to know how to convert these corrections to probabilities (non-negative numbers).[H2o decision tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUF3U.png)

Answer (score 0):

Variants of this question have been asked and answered several times.

The best way to really know what is going on is to debug the code in a java debugger and single-step it.  I recommend IntelliJ IDEA.

I recommend copying one of the snippets in the following document:

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/index.html

and then single-stepping through the predict method call in the Easy Wrapper and then the score0 low-level method call.

The code is all open source so you can cross-reference what you see in the debugger with github source code and comments.